# IntelliJ Console not showing the system.println statements

Tags: intellij-idea, println

I have setup JBoss locally in intellij and been testing my code locally. I used to see all the System.out.println statements when i deploy and start the server. But it is not showing all the print statements recently. What am i missing here? Appreciate any comments.

It shows the error/exception. however, i have print statement right before that which is not showing up at all.

[image]

I also have these 2 options checked in the JBoss configuration.

[image]

Comment: Does this message go to the stdout of the server or does it go to some log file? How is the logging configured in your app and what code do you use to log this message? If you start the server manually outside of the IDE, deploy your app, will you see this message in the console output?

Comment: It usually shows the stdout in the console within intellij. After i add local jboss config in intellij and deploy the code, it shows all of the stdout that i have in the code. But not anymore. So not sure if something is changed.

Comment: In this case you will need to provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and describe the setup needed to reproduce the issue.